# Choose random numbers

Tags: prolog

I have this function:

```
:- use_module(library(random)).

choose(A, C, B) :- B is random(A), (B\=2, choose(A,C,B));(B == 2, !).
```

How can I make this function generate numbers from 0 to A, different from C and save the result 
in B?

Thanks.

Comment: `choose(A, C, B) :- B is random(A), B \= C.`

Comment: When I do choose(5,3,R). when random gives 3 it returns false instead of generate other number until it is different from C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
choose(A, C, B) :- repeat, B is random(A), B \= C, !.
```